# How to fill in a letter with a pattern?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, patterns, creative-cloud

I was given this image to work with:

http://safaviehhome.com/promotional/test2.jpg

The client is happy with everything but would like the floral pattern/bush to fill in the **O**

What is the best way to do this in Photoshop CC? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe drop a circle shape in the layer below the **O** and apply the pattern overlay or duplicate one of the trees to the sides and apply it as a clipping mask.

Comment: The clipping mask suggestion worked great. Thanks!

Comment: You are most welcome.